# String name to access nodejs website on static ip

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, ip, intranet

I am working in intranet enviornment, and one machine has a static ip, 10.10.10.10:3000. I have deployed my nodejs server client on this computer and people in intranet can access it by http://10.10.10.10:3000.
I need to change this to something like http://abawa.alladin.com:3000, is it possible to do with access to only my machine or do i need some help of IT admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to contact your IT admin because you will have to install a DNS on your server.

Comment: Indeed. They have to tell the computers on your intranet that when they go to that address they are being pointed to that IP. That is the idea.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes it's exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your hosts file.

Modifying your hosts file causes your local machine to look directly at the Internet Protocol (IP) address that you specify. Rackspace offers managed hosting solutions to assist with the handling of these resources.

```
10.10.10.10 www.domain.com domain.com
```

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

windows path `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

linux or mac `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost).

edit /etc/hosts:

```
10.10.10.10   abawa.alladin.com:3000
```

Following is example for `vhost` with `express`

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var express = require('../..');
var logger = require('morgan');
var vhost = require('vhost');

// Main server app
var main = express();

if (!module.parent) main.use(logger('dev'));

main.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello from main app!');
});

main.get('/:sub', function(req, res){
  res.send('requested ' + req.params.sub);
});

// Redirect app
var redirect = express();

redirect.use(function(req, res){
  if (!module.parent) console.log(req.vhost);
  res.redirect('http://abawa.alladin.com:3000/' + req.vhost[0]);
});

// Vhost app
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(vhost('*.alladin.com', redirect)); // Serves all subdomains via Redirect app
app.use(vhost('alladin.com', main)); // Serves top level domain via Main server app

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
```